# Why is WebBrowser DocumentCompleted only firing when all images are loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in my application, I thought `DocumentCompleted` is fired right after the body is loaded, with or without images, but that's not the case.

The body is loaded and the images take a while to load, and the event is not fired until all images are loaded.

How can I avoid this and fire the event right after body is loaded? (I don't care about the images)

Comment: And if the page contains Frames or other sub-elements with text, maybe all the text, do you care about those being loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you want the Navigated event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx

sorry this isnt just a comment, I'm missing the link for that just now :S

Comment: I think your answer really is an 'answer'; the `DocumentCompleted` event works as described, and you have given info on what he would need to hook into to get the behavior he wants.

Comment: Thanks man, I feel dumb for not checking all the class methods first before asking...